Seeking Advice: Best Approach for Parsing SEC Proxy Filing Compensation Tables into JSON
I'm working on a project where I need to extract compensation/award table data from SEC proxy filings and convert it into a structured JSON format. The tables have a consistent format across documents but are not identical.
Here's an example of a Netflix filing I'm working with: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1065280/000119312522115102/d202881ddef14a.htm
I'm considering several approaches and would appreciate your input:
Using GCP AI Document Parser: Is it advisable to convert the HTML documents to PDF and then segment them into 15-page chunks for this tool? Will this method effectively identify and parse the tables?
Custom Coding: Should I write custom code using libraries to detect the start and end of tables directly in the HTML? I'm thinking about converting the HTML to formatted text via an API to clean up any non-relevant data. Any library recommendations?
Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG): I've tried using the RAG approach, but I'm finding it challenging due to the large size of some tables, which don't fit well into the context window. Has anyone successfully used RAG for large data extraction tasks like this?
Which method would you recommend or is there another approach that I might be overlooking? Thank you for your assistance!
